# Git fails to add file change

Tags: git, bitbucket

Some weeks ago, I had quite an unusual issue with Git.
Here's the error message when i try to push:

```
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
remote: error: inflate: data stream error (invalid stored block lengths)
remote: error: inflate returned -3
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
```

Remark: adding a new small file is working.

Comment: It's not unusual: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+remote+unpack+failed%3A+unpack-objects+abnormal+exit